# Reverse Engineering of a AC speed controller

Tags: switches

Recently I've bought one of these AC speed controllers [AC Speed controller](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-10PCS-AC-220V-2000W-SCR-Voltage-Regulator-Dimming-Dimmers-Speed-Controller-Thermostat/32787576167.html) from china. After a few tests the BTA16-600BW Triac blew up, so I tried to reverse engineer this controller.

Here are the Images of the top and bottom
[image]
[image]

This is the circuit which I got from reverse engineering

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJyUL0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Actually I dont understand how this circuit works.
As far as I know, the C2, R4,R1 andf R2 network is used to genarate the pulses to turn on the triac. but how exactly does it work?

Comment: This is a standard triac-based dimmer circuit for lights.

Comment: Did you try to Google for "triac dimmer"?

Comment: 100% standard triac circuit. The caveat is this circuit is only suited for  resistive-inductive loads. You cannot put a highly capacitive load behind it. The BTA16 is sure buff but it can't handle this either.

Comment: The distances between high voltage tracks are too small. The PCB should not be used.

Comment: Very strange PCB design. The silk screen should cover all tracks, only the pads should be uncovered. The small tin covered tracks do not make sense.

Comment: @Uwe. The tinned tracks are to provide better current carrying capability on a board with too thin copper. You see this done a lot on cheap China based designs.

Comment: You have L-out and L-in crossed. The RC network connects to the AC-in.

Comment: @ Jack Creasey: The tinned tracks decrease of resistance is neglible, the conductivity of solder tin is much less than that of copper. The current carrying capability is not better with tinned tracks.

Comment: @Jack Creasy: I have not crossed In and Out. I checked it several times. Thats why I have been confused about the schematic. But I did understand, the principle is the same, even if In and out are crossed

Comment: @UWE. What?? Of course the solder reduces the resistance. Consider the conductivity of the copper and the solder in parallel. http://www.kappalloy.com/antimony-tin-solder.php   The solder is many times thicker than the copper, so it's resistance influences more. Is it as good as copper ...no ...but does it make a difference ….it sure does.

Comment: @S.G It does make a difference if In and Out are crossed. If the RC is connected to the mains in all the time the RC/DIAC will continue to charge and trigger. This is not a problem while the Triac is on, but results in odd firing times when it turns off for the next cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RC pair \$C_2 \cdot (R_4 + R_1||R_2)\$ provide a delay as C2 charges from the initial voltage to the breakdown voltage of the diac (typically around +/-35V). It's not calculated as a simple RC delay since the voltage is a half sine wave.

When that breakdown voltage is met, C2 discharges through the triac gate, triggering it and the remainder of the AC half-cycle passes through to the output.

C1+R3 form a snubber for the triac.

The trimpot is used to adjust the low end of the adjustment, as pots (and capacitors) have poor tolerance.

As others have said, this is just a old-style triac light dimmer circuit (minus any attempt to mitigate EMI) such as you might have found in a house 30 or 40 years ago.